# maven testng project - after change testng.xml, it didn't changed when I executed from terminal

Tags: java, maven, testng

I have a maven testng project, and I execute testng.xml file to run testng tests

```
mvn clean test -DsuiteXmlFile=testng.xml
```

Later, I changed some classes in testng.xml file, when I run it from eclipse it works as expected. But when I use the command to run the tests, looks like it still executed tests in previous version of testng.xml.

1. I have tried mvn clean, and project clean. but still got same results.

Q: How can I fix this? what's the correct way to run it with mvn commands?

Comment: change the name so it forces it to reload?

Comment: i've tried it, doesn't work for me. but if i run from eclipse it works. maybe sth wrong when i created the project.

Comment: hope you are lucky with this one. I personally hate maven will all my soul : )

Comment: Are you running the command from your xml file folder? If not you can add the path or drag the file to terminal as the parameter value. And maybe your pom.xml file declares the old xml file version. For running as Maven you need surefire plugin with some parameters.